# Unable to retrieve the requested metadata /latest/meta-data/public-hostname

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-aws

I'm deploying a springboot application with spring-cloud-stream and binder for AWS Kinesis.
The application works fine when is deployed on aws elastic beanstalk if the beanstalk is configured with public ip.
When we set beanstalk with private ip, the application throws warnings at deploy because is unable to get some metadata from aws.

Why is trying to get these resorurces?
There are some workaround to remove this warnings?

These are warnings thrown when application is deployed and no public ip is set on ec2.

```
 com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4). The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:122)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:82)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:400)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:369)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:365)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ec2.AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource.getProperty(AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource.java:89)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.collectEncryptedProperties(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:199)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:649)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:250)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:174)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:120)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:313)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:214)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:262)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:55)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:47)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1135)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1869)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils      : Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/meta-data/public-hostname). The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:122)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2CredentialsUtils.readResource(EC2CredentialsUtils.java:82)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getItems(EC2MetadataUtils.java:400)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:369)
        at com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils.getData(EC2MetadataUtils.java:365)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.ec2.AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource.getProperty(AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource.java:89)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.collectEncryptedProperties(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:199)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:96)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:649)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:373)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinderInstance(DefaultBinderFactory.java:250)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:174)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:120)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:313)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:214)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(BindableProxyFactory.java:262)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:55)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:47)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1135)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1869)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I've edited question because the apllication works fine. Only throws warnings.
I've tried to recompile spring-cloud-aws-core removing public-hostname and 
public-ipv4 from AmazonEc2InstanceDataPropertySource.properties and then starts without warnings.

Comment: any know solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 19):

This exception is happening within the Amazon SDK. If you simply don't like the stacktrace, you can update your logging configuration to only report at the ERROR level for com.amazonaws. If you don't need any of the instance data for the EC2 instance you are running on, you can add or update the annotation

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

on one of your configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

Its, related to [Retrieve instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) . Looks like it's a log message handling issue. This can be easily handled by not logging the exception using the application.properties file .

> logging.level.com.amazonaws.util.EC2MetadataUtils=error

Answer (score 0):

This is how OnAwsCloudEnvironmentCondition works. In order to understand if the application is executed on an AWS environment, it tries to get instance metadata https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Indeed it's just a log message triggered during `@ConditionalOnAwsCloudEnvironment` evaluation.

To avoid this error just exclude those files -->

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class,
    org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class,
    org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration.class
```

})